# I have an array of objects and an object I want to loop through an object while matching object values with the values in the array

Tags: javascript

I want to loop through a variable which has ten answers as its values, those ten values must be matched with values on the object so that I can get the strings which are associated with values on answers variable.

var possibleValues = [
            {
                value1:'Completly Agree',
                weight:5
            },
            {
                value1:'Highly Agree',
                weight:4
            },
            {
                value1:'Partialy Agree',
                weight:3
            },
            {
                value1:'Highly Disagree',
                weight:2
            },
            {
                value1:'Completly Disagree',
                weight:1
            }
            ];

```
        var answers = [1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 2, 5, 1, 2, 5];
        var result = '';

        /*Loop through answers variable and possibleValues array of objects
         find match between answers value and possibleValues weight
         then if there is a match save value1's value in the result variable*/

        for(i=0;i<answers.length;i++){
            if(possibleValues[i].weight===answers[i].value){
                result = possibleValues[i].value1;
            }
            alert(result);
        }
```

I want to Loop through answers variable and possibleValues array of objects, find match between answers value and possibleValues weight, then if there is a match save value1's value in the result variable.

THIS IS HOW RESULT VARIABLE MUST  LOOK LIKE AFTER ALL
result = ['Completly Disagree', 'Partialy Agree', 'Completly Disagree', 'Highly Agree', 'Highly Disagree', 'Highly Disagree', 'Completly Agree', 'Completly Disagree', 'Highly Disagree', 'Completly Agree'];

Comment: Why not just store the descriptions in an array, and then retrieve it like `result[0] = possibleValues[answers[0] - 1];` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```js
var possibleValues = [
    {value1: "Completly Agree", weight: 5},
    {value1: "Highly Agree", weight: 4},
    {value1: "Partialy Agree", weight: 3},
    {value1: "Highly Disagree", weight: 2},
    {value1: "Completly Disagree", weight: 1}
];

var answers = [1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 2, 5, 1, 2, 5];
var result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
    possibleValues.forEach(function (element) {
        if (answers[i] == element.weight) {
            result[i] = element.value1;
        }
    });
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) with all values and `weight` as keys.

For the wanted result, map the weights by getting the value from the map.

```js
var possibleValues = [{ value1: 'Completly Agree', weight: 5 }, { value1: 'Highly Agree', weight: 4 }, { value1: 'Partialy Agree', weight: 3 }, { value1: 'Highly Disagree', weight: 2 }, { value1: 'Completly Disagree', weight: 1 }],
    answers = [1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 2, 5, 1, 2, 5],
    result = answers.map(
        Map.prototype.get,
        possibleValues.reduce((m, { value1, weight }) => m.set(weight, value1), new Map)
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use an object with the values, then `map()` the array over simply by using the object's values:

```js
 

var values = {
    5: "Completely Agree",
    4: "Highly Agree",
    3: "Partially Agree",
    2: "Highly Disagree",
    1: "Completely Disagree"
};

var answers = [1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 2, 5, 1, 2, 5];
var result = answers.map(e => values[e]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
 

.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
    top: 0;
}
```